# How do I check and count if a list contains both elements of a tuple, but order doesn't matter

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have two lists:

```
list_a = [[2,6,7,1], [1,9,4],[2,6,7], [4,1,6,2,8,9,3]]
list_b = [(1,2), (6,9), (2,7)]
```

How do I check that each element in list a contains both elements of each tuple in list b? Order doesn't matter.

An example of the results I want to get. Not necessarily in this format, but I'd like  to end up with these truth values. It would need to be repeated for each element in `list_a`, but thought it wouldn't be worth writing this out three times. I just wanted to give the general idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
(1,2) in [2,6,7,1] = True
(1,2) in [1,9,4] = False
(1,2) in [2,6,7] = False
(1,2) in [4,1,6,2,8,9,3] = True
(1,2) occurrence count = 2
```

I've tried using a For loop with lots of if statements and more or less have managed to get it working, so I've tried writing a list comprehension, but keep getting false so I'm really stuck:

My For Loop:

```
for tup in list_b:
    for ele in list_a:
        if tup[0] in list_a and tup[1] in list_b:
            counter += 1
            boo = True
        else:
            boo = False
```

The issue with this For loop is that list_a has a *lot* of sub-lists and the execution time is really slow.

I tried writing the below list comprehension hoping it would run a bit faster, but I keep getting false. So I'm unsure on how to edit this or any other approach I could take.
My list comprehension:

```
outcome = [x.count(all(list_b)) for x in list_a]
```

Just to clarify, while this is part of a larger homework exercise I can't get working, it forms one function of about 20, this isn't the whole assignment.

Comment: Please post your "more or less" working code

Comment: Please also post your *full* expected output. There should be three times that much, no?

Comment: Try breaking down the problem. How would you do it by hand?

Comment: If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) as well as [ask] more generally.

Comment: updated, although this is part of an assignment, it's just one part of a function that I can't get working. It isn't the whole assignment.

Comment: That for-loop is not correct... `counter` is undefined and never reset, `boo` is unused, and you're checking `tup[1] in list_b`.

Comment: I'm asking for your exact desired output because it's not totally clear what your end goal is. Do you actually need the result for each sublist in `list_a`, or just their count? And do you need the count for each tuple in `list_b` or just the overall count? I assumed you want the count for each tuple, i.e. `[2, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Depending on what your actual desired output is, you might be able to use `set` or `collections.Counter` on the contents of `list_a` to get better performance.

Comment: For reference, see [mre]